# Optional ForeignKey in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to validate a form which contains an optional FK:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    mandatory_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    optional_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
class Show(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    optional_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, blank=True, null=True)

class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address

class ShowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Show
```

In the view form, I would like to perform the validation like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ShowForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        do anything...
```

But I don't know how to validate the AddressForm. This validation should be done if at least one field of Address is filled. As the AddressForm has a mandatory field, I cannot validate it each time.

Do you have an idea to include the validation of the address in the validation of the show form?

Thank you,
Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to make the field "optional_address" mandatory if there is at least 1 address instance

```
class ShowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Show

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ShowForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if Address.objects.exists():
            self.fields['optional_address'].required = True
```

Comment: Thank you TigorC for your answer. In fact I would like to validate the AddressForm inside the ShowForm. For this I need to check the AddressForm only if we have the mandatory_field or optional_field filled. Then, I would like to be able to save the Address and the Show by doing only one form.save(). I think this can be handle by overriding the validate methode and the save methode but I am not sure that the best way to handle this.